# turing machine logic instead of something

Tags: turing-machines

Lets assume I have this turing machine:

[image: tm_except_something]

And I have a $\Sigma = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Now my question is can I simplify the transaction from $A$ to $B$ ?

Is there any way so I can write - when the read **value is not $2$**, write $x$ and move to right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write $\neq 2 \to x,R$, but you might have to explain somewhere that by that you mean that the transition is taken as long as the symbol read is not $2$.

More generally, you can use whatever notation you want as long as you explain it and it's unambiguous.

This is the answer of a practical mathematician. Your professor could have different ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write sth like "Σ\2 → x, R" on the transition. But as Yuval Filmus mentioned, the notations always depend on the lecturer.